# Gradle: no tests found for given includes with Cucumber runner

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to run single Cucumber test using Intellij IDEA with Gradle.

I'm getting following error:

```
> No tests found for given includes: [mypackage.CucumberTest]
```

I have following CucumberTest class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class CucumberTest {
}
```

If I run all tests with `gradle test` Cucumber test is running fine.

If I run single Cucumber test **using Intellij JUnit build configuration** Cucumber test is running fine.

How can I make single Cucumber test running fine **using Intellij Gradle build configuration**?

**UPD:**

Adding empty test can be used as workaround:

```
@Test
public void dummyTest(){}
```

Comment: You must add at least one test method in your test class.

Comment: thanks, Walsh. Adding empty test helps to make it running. But it seems a bit weird from clean code prospective. Can we avoid adding it while keeping test running?

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the above comments and nothing works for me.

I think you need Junit4 (vintage) to make it work, since @RunWith is Junit4 annotation. (this post also points it out but the solution there not works for me https://thecodinganalyst.github.io/knowledgebase/No-tests-found-when-running-cucumber-junit/ )

Solution:

If you stick with Junit5, an alternative (if you use gradle) is to define a task using CLI, like mentioned here https://www.baeldung.com/java-cucumber-gradle

That will work for me.

Just define task for cucumberCli, and then run " ./gradlew cucumberCli
" in your terminal. It will execute all tests and generate report.

Feel free to point out any issues to me. Thx!

Shizheng

Comment: Plz clarify your answer and provide steps to follow and code that can be used to show how you solve the issue.